# Read data from newly written TempFile doesn't work? IOerror closed stream in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ioerror, temporary-files

I am implementing in Ruby on Rails, and i have 2 views. In my first view i read in a file and show the first rows (this works fine), then in my second view ( in the method in the controller ) i write a temporary file. Just the same. And i want to show the content of this temporary file again. But this doesn't work, I always get the error :

```
IOError in Project importerController#result

closed stream
```

this is my code in the controller, behind the first view i do:

```
 tmpfile = Tempfile.new("tempfile")
    if tmpfile     
      tmpfile.write(@samples)
      tmpfile.close
      tmpfilename = File.basename(tmpfile.path)
      tmpfilenametest = tmpfilename
      if !$tmpfiles
        $tmpfiles = Hash.new
      end
      $tmpfiles[tmpfilename] = tmpfile
    else
      flash[:error] = "Cannot save import file."
      return
    end
    @path = tmpfile.path
    session[:importer_tmpfile] = tmpfilename
   end
```

and then in my next view , I want to read this file by:

```
 tmpfilename = session[:importer_tmpfile]
      i = 0
      sample_count = 5

      if tmpfilename
      tmpfile = $tmpfiles[tmpfilename]
      if tmpfile == nil
        flash[:error] = "Tijdelijk bestand bestaat niet!"
        return
      end
    end


    fields_map = params[:fields_map]
      attrs_map = fields_map.invert

      @parsed_tempfile=CSV::Reader.parse(tmpfile)
       @sampletemp = []
     @parsed_tempfile.each  do |row| 

          @sampletemp[i] = row  

        i = i+1  

     end
```

In this view i just want to show it, i just have:

```
<ul>
<% @sampletemp.each do |x| %>
<li>
<%= x %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Does anybody see what i am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, a Tempfile only lasts until you close it - then it is no longer valid. If you want to actually save data in a file that sticks around after you close it - then you'll need to use a real File.

Edit;
According to our discussion, I don't think you need a tempfile at all. You are just displaying parts of the file-data that the user has uploaded for you. You don't need a real file object for that (tempfile or otherwise).

The user uploads a "file" and you can parse the CSV (as you've done) then afterwards you can just treat it as an array of strings. Save it in an @var like "@csv_lines" and in your views access the array @csv_lines however you need to.

Comment: So I have to delete tmpfile.close?

Comment: No that won't work. If you want the file to stick around when you go to another view... then you have to use a real File. Really save it and open it up in the other view. At least that's what I gathered you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes this is what i am trying to do. But the file already exists, I read this in, the user browses it, and it goes to my controller with params[:file], but what should i do in the next view? Because i just do in the first view  @parsed_file=CSV::Reader.parse(params[:file]), I can't just put this in a session? So i put the path in the session and then Make a new file?

Comment: Ok, so if the file already exists, you can stop using Tempfile and start using File. Just open the file, read from it/write it whatever - and int he other view do the same.

I think you're confusing the file *name* here with the actual saved file. or possibly a file *stream* passed inf rom somebody uploading a file - to an actual saved file.

If the user has passed in an uploaded file - then create a real File saved onto the system, and the re-open and read it then. The tempfile simply won't hang around between a controller and view.

Comment: otherwise - can you please explain more fully what you're doing with the file. How you're getting it, what you want to be doing with it, wether it is just a filename, an uploaded file, or a file saved on your system...

Comment: I just want that, in the first view, the user browses to a file. This is passed to the controller with params[:file] then In the second view i show the first lines of the CSV file and then in the third just again the same. It looks stupid but it is just the idea. So if i'm correct. You say that i just have to create a file, sort of a copy of the selected file by the user. And then work with that file?

Comment: In this case no - I don't think you need a file object at all. I'll add my thoughts to my answer.

Comment: Off course. Sorry it was stupid of me. Really thank you for your help!

Comment: Indeed, a `Tempfile` does not exist any longer than it takes Rails to handle your request. If you need a file that survives a Rails request, use a real `File`.

Comment: ty, in retrospect it makes sense that Tempfile has this behavior.  Perhaps it might help others find this SO quicker, so here's a related error message I had via resque.  "Received Input/output error @ io_write - <STDOUT>"